# How to add Testing Library (e.g. JUnit) to Intellij "Create Test Class" dialog

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea

The "Create Test" dialog (accessed via Alt-Enter) is being launched. But it only shows SCALA test libraries (Specs and ScalaTest).   How do I get it to show JUnit ?

Note: this is a Maven project and JUnit4.10 is already included in the dependencies - as shown by the second screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the JUnit plugin, which is bundled with IntelliJ, is checked in the Plugins section. How you do this varies according to your OS (and therefore which flavor you've installed).

Comment: thx the Junit plugin was unchecked, i checked it and am restarting. Pls consider to upvote question.

Comment: Glad to hear it. You can never have enough testing. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with TestNG. 
I used Intellij 14.1.6 and Ubuntu.
In My case, somehow testng folder in $Intellij_Home/plugins was deleted. I extracted the testng folder from Intellij Idea tar ball and copied it to plugin folder. Then I **file -> Invalidates caches/ Restart** the IDEA. 
Now it's on the create Test dialog box. 
Hope Some one find this methodology useful.